# Ember.js/Ember-Data: Using the RESTAdapter to load data from multiple endpoints

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an API that returns one resource at a time.

As an example, say I have two related resources:

- `Topics`
- `Posts`

`Topics` hasMany `Posts`, and `Posts` belongsTo a `Topic`.

According to the documentation (and everything I've tried and have been reading about), Ember-Data expects the JSON out of the API to be similar to the following, where both the data for `Topic` and the data for `Posts` are provided simultaneously.

```
"topic": {
  "id": ...,
  "title": ...,
  "author": ...
},

"posts": [{
  "id": ...,
  "commenter": ...,
  "text": ...
}, {
  "id": ...,
  "commenter": ...,
  "text": ...
}]
```

As I mentioned at the start of the post, my API does not do this.  It would return the `Topic` data in one call, and the `Posts` data for that `Topic` in a second call.  Changing my API to work exactly how Ember wants it is not an option.

**My question is**, how can I extend/override the RESTAdapter and RESTSerializer in Ember-Data to support loading data from multiple API calls?  Is this even possible?

I tried following this example, but it looks like the data here is already loaded (it tries to sideload data that is already known to the system):  http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/loading-json-with-embedded-records-into-ember-data-1-0-0-beta/

I also tried to override the `extractFindAll` function of the `ApplicationSerializer`, but can't figure out how to get the rest (no pun intended) of the application to wait for all of the relationships to load.  I iterate through all of the relationships on the model, and load their data, but I don't see a way to shuttle that data back into the original payload:

```
extractFindAll: function (store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
  var promises = [];

  type.eachRelationship(function (key, relationship) {
    promise.push(Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      this.store.find(key, payloadEntry[key]);
    }));
  });

  // can't figure out how to get the relationship payloads
  // back to the original payload
  Ember.RSVP.addSettled(promises).then(function () { 
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  });
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That exactly describes using the `async` property.

### Models

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bars: DS.hasMany('bar', {async: true});
})


App.Bar = DS.Model.extend({
  baz: DS.attr()
})
```

### Adapters

```
App.FooAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  //anything custom
});

App.BarAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  //anything custom    
});
```

- If you don't do anything custom, you should just define `App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;` to be a site wide adapter.

### Serializer

```
App.FooSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  //anything custom
});

App.BarSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  //anything custom    
});
```

- If you don't do anything custom, you don't need to define the rest serializers, they will use their default serializer associated with whichever adapter they're using.

#### Example

Important to note, I was lazy and my mock response for bars always returns the same thing regardless of any call to `/bar*`

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/481/edit

Comment: Ah, thanks!  I had tried the async property before, but I think I had an error in my serializer.  Thanks again!